# Can not save array in shared object as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, shared-objects

I have this code in my simple flash. I want to save name and score in my quiz. My code reference in this website http://www.mollyjameson.com/blog/local-flash-game-leaderboard-tutorial/

I want to make my code in just one actionscript. But I didn't success do it.

```
var m_FlashCookie = SharedObject.getLocal("LeaderboardExample");

var EntryName:String ="nama kamu";
var EntryScore:String ="nilai";
const NUM_SCORES_SAVED:int = 10;

inputBoxScore.text = EntryScore;
inputBoxName.text = EntryName

var latest_score_object:Object = {
  name: EntryName,
  score: EntryScore
};

var arr:Array;
arr = m_FlashCookie.data.storedArray

if ( arr == null)
{
    arr = new Array();
}

arr.push( latest_score_object );
arr.sortOn("score", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);

if ( arr.length < NUM_SCORES_SAVED )
{
  arr.pop();
}

btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveData);
function saveData(event:Event):void
{
      m_FlashCookie.data.arr = arr;
      m_FlashCookie.flush();
}

var myHTMLL:String = "";
var total_stored_scores:int = arr.length;

btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadData);
function loadData(event:Event):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < total_stored_scores; ++i)
    {
      // loop through every entry, every entry has a "name" and "score" field as that's what we save.
      var leaderboard_entry:Object = arr[i];

      // is this the last score that was just entered last gamestate?
      if ( leaderboard_entry == latest_score_object )
      {
        myHTMLL += (i+1) + ". <b><font color=\"#0002E5\">"+ leaderboard_entry.name + " " + leaderboard_entry.score +"</font></b><br>";
      }
      else
      {
        myHTMLL += (i+1) + ". "+ leaderboard_entry.name + " " + leaderboard_entry.score +"<br>";
      }
    }
    myHTML.text = myHTMLL;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What about this was not a success?

Comment: I can't save or load from the button. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the array as `data.arr` but reading the array as `data.storedArray`. You need to make them the same.

In other words, you've written this:

```
m_FlashCookie.data.arr = arr;
```

And when you load:

```
arr = m_FlashCookie.data.storedArray;
```

This clearly doesn't make sense: `data.storedArray` is never set, so it will never have a value, so you will always end up with a new empty array.

You need to use the same property on the shared object `data`. For example:

```
m_FlashCookie.data.storedArray = arr;
m_FlashCookie.flush();
```

---

Looking at your code, there's a number of other issues:

1. The latest score is immediately removed because `arr.length < NUM_SAVED_SCORES` is going to be true from the start, since `arr` starts out empty, and it then calls `arr.pop()` which will remove the latest entry that was just added. So the array is always empty.
2. It adds the score immediately with `arr.push(latest_score_object)` instead of waiting until the user clicks save, so the value of the input texts don't matter at all -- the saved values will always be "nama kamu" and "nilai".

The following fixes all the issues mentioned:

```
var leaderboard = SharedObject.getLocal("leaderboard");

const MAX_SAVED_SCORES:int = 10;

inputBoxName.text = "nama kamu";
inputBoxScore.text = "nilai";

var entries:Array = leaderboard.data.entries || [];

var latestEntry:Object;

displayScores();

btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadClick);
btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveClick);

function loadClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    displayScores();
}

function saveClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    saveLatestScore();
    displayScores();
}

function saveLatestScore():void {

    // create the latest entry based on input texts
    latestEntry = {
      name: inputBoxName.text,
      score: inputBoxScore.text
    };

    // add the entry and sort by score, highest to lowest
    entries.push(latestEntry);
    entries.sortOn("score", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);

    // if reached the limit, remove lowest score
    if (entries.length > MAX_SAVED_SCORES) {
      entries.pop();
    }

    // store new sorted entries to shared object
    leaderboard.data.entries = entries;
    leaderboard.flush();
}

function displayScores():void {
    var myHTMLL:String = "";

    for (var i:int = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
      // loop through every entry, every entry has a "name" and "score" field as that's what we save.
      var entry:Object = entries[i];

      // is this the last score that was just entered last gamestate?
      if (entry == latestEntry)
        myHTMLL += (i+1) + ". <b><font color=\"#0002E5\">"+ entry.name + " " + entry.score +"</font></b><br/>";
      else
        myHTMLL += (i+1) + ". "+ entry.name + " " + entry.score +"<br/>";
    }
    myHTML.htmlText = myHTMLL;
}
```

Comment: Then, what should I do? This is my first time using shared object.

Comment: You need to make them the same.

Comment: I fix it, but my button save and load didn't work. Nothing.

Comment: It looks like your code immediately removes the score that it adds, because `arr.length < NUM_SCORES_SAVED`. What is that code trying to accomplish?